# C# 2008 Printing to Preexisting Page Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, forms, printing

I'm doing some work for a Laboratory, helping with an application that prints all the tests results.

The results are printed on a "pre-printed" form, this is a custom form they had made, I believe they already have several boxes of this form.

I need to figure out how to print on top of it and make everything align correctly.

Any one have good ideas to solving this problem?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Print out a grid, then align your output based on this grid.

*edit*

By "grid", I don't mean lines forming boxes, I mean a repeated sequence of "0123456789", which you can then use to match any area of the pre-printed form to the coordinates of your output.

Comment: Thanks. I remember doing this in an old legacy app written in VB6. I've been reading a book and looks like it's done basically the same way. Thank you Steven.